# Cocos Creator js animate sprite

Tags: animation, sprite, cocos2d-x, cocoscreator

I have animated a sprite using a sprite sheet and the update function,
like so:

Note: I have dragged the plist into the atlas field of the sprite node (the same node the monster.js script is attached to) in the Ccos Creator UI.

```
//monster.js
onLoad: function(){
// change monsters face
            this.faces['1'] =  'monster1';
            this.faces['2'] =  'monster2';
            this.faces['3'] =  'Rmonster1';
            this.faces['4'] =  'Rmonster2';

}
    update: function (dt) {


    this.timekeep += dt;

    if(this.timekeep > 0.1){

var self = this;
          cc.loader.loadRes('monsters', cc.SpriteAtlas, function (err, atlas) {
  self.getComponent(cc.Sprite).spriteFrame = atlas.getSpriteFrame(self.faces[self.monstersN]);
});     

                this.timekeep = 0;

                this.monstersN++;
                if(this.monstersN > 4){

                    this.monstersN = 1;

                }
            }
```

It actually works fine. I have already thought I should export the cc.loader.loaderRes into the onLoad function and save the atlas as a global var instead of loading every time the update is called.

However…seeing that there are built in animation functions, this can’t be the correct solution. So I tried this:

```
onLoad: function () {
            // change monster face
            this.faces['1'] =  'monster1';
            this.faces['2'] =  'monster2';
            this.faces['3'] =  'Rmonster1';
            this.faces['4'] =  'Rmonster2';
            var self = this;
                  cc.loader.loadRes('monsters', cc.SpriteAtlas, function (err, atlas) {
var sprite = self.getComponent(cc.Sprite);

        var animFrames = [];
 for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {   
     var spriteFrame = atlas.getSpriteFrame(self.faces[i]);
        var animFrame = new cc.AnimationFrame();
            animFrame.initWithSpriteFrame(spriteFrame, 1, null);
        animFrames.push(animFrame);
 }      
 var animation = sprite.Animation.create(animFrames, 0.2, 100);
    var animate   = sprite.Animate.create(animation); 

    sprite.runAction(animate); 
              });    


        },
```

I get this error:

> cc.AnimationFrame is not a constructor

So then I tried this:

```
onLoad: function () {

            // change monster face
            this.faces['1'] =  'monster1';
            this.faces['2'] =  'monster2';
            this.faces['3'] =  'Rmonster1';
            this.faces['4'] =  'Rmonster2';
            var self = this;
                  cc.loader.loadRes('monsters', cc.SpriteAtlas, function (err, atlas) {
self.atlasA = atlas;
              });    

 var sprite = this.getComponent(cc.Sprite);

        var animFrames = [];
 for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {   
     var spriteFrame = this.atlasA.getSpriteFrame(this.faces[i]);
    var animFrame = new cc.AnimationFrame();
        animFrame.initWithSpriteFrame(spriteFrame, 1, null);
    animFrames.push(animFrame);
 }      
 var animation = sprite.Animation.create(animFrames, 0.2, 100);
var animate   = sprite.Animate.create(animation); 

sprite.runAction(animate); 

        },
```

I get this error:

> Cannot read property ‘getSpriteFrame’ of undefined

How can I use cc.animate to change the sprite using the spritesheet I have. All I want to achieve is to move through the plist in the order the images are in the plist, repeated until the monster is put back into the pool it came from.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: SO is no longer a place to get answers. :-(

Comment: I do not recommend passive-aggressive remarks intended to coerce people into helping you. The ideal response to my boilerplate remark is "Sorry, you're right: I won't add that again". If you can remember that most readers are volunteers here, aside from a few technology advocates, that will serve you very well. People like helping here, but no-one is under any obligation to.

Comment: Wasting my time here i know but i have no idea what your talking about anyway. Aparently i put urgent in my post. i cant see where iv'e put that. Anyway i found some much better places to get some help from so do what you want with this. I'Il leave you to enjoy it by yourself :-) Just to clarify, there's no aggression at all. just disappointment because i used to like this place.

Comment: See the [edit history here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49696451/revisions). Don't take the standards and guidelines here personally, David - they're there for a reason. Of course, you can always [post on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) if you have suggestions on how the site could better operate - just be willing to expect short shrift from established users.

Comment: For what it's worth, your question does not seem so bad. The areas you need to improve on (and I mean this constructively) are: Markdown formatting, case correctness, and expectations of volunteers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution for anyone who may still be looking.....

```
cc.AnimationClip.createWithSpriteFrames([sf1, sf2, ...], fps)
```